# How to display html page in Kivy in a simple widget or window?

Tags: python, html, user-interface, kivy, display

I have a function returning an HTML file in Python (a folium map) and I would like to display it directly in my Kivy GUI without opening a Web browser window!

The only info I found about it on the Internet is at least 5 years old so maybe some new solutions exist now!

Comment: what info ? Add link for this info.

Comment: There isn't really anything except the old cefpython garden stuff. That might still work, on platforms that cefpython supports.

Comment: Also for basic html __without images__, you can convert it to markup and display it with a Label.. ;o)

Comment: @furas it was a script opening a browser and making a screenshot which was not working with Kivy.

Comment: I want to run it on android or ios, is it supported @inclement ?

Comment: @noEmbryo unfortunately it's a folium map so not really basic I guess :/

Comment: On Android/iOS you can open a webview and display html that way, but that's not part of the kivy application (or, to be specific it *is* part of the kivy application but not part of Kivy's drawing layer and widget tree)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to look for another extension to display maps then.. Maybe Google